# How to insert values inside a list that is inside an inner class?

Tags: wrapper, inner-classes, apex

How can I insert values inside a list that is inside an inner class? In the example below, `wc.add(ordersNew)` does not work.

```
public class wrapperClass {
    public List<Account> accountList {get; set;}
    public List<Contact> contactList = new list<Contact>();
    public List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
}


public wrapperClass createNewOrders(List<String> ordersName) {
    
    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>(Order);

    for(String orderName : ordersName){
    
        orderList.add(new Order(
            Name = orderName));         
    }

    wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();

    wc.add(ordersNew);
    
    return wc;                      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply assigning the new list to the wrapper list.

```
public wrapperClass createNewOrders(List<String> ordersName) {

    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>(Order);

    for(String orderName : ordersName){

        orderList.add(new Order(
            Name = orderName
        ));         
    }

    wrapperClass wc = new wrapperClass();

    wc.orderList = ordersNew;

    return wc;                      
}
```

Also when you want to add a list to another list you might want to use the addAll method. [List addAll method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#:%7E:text=addAll(fromList),be%20of%20the%20same%20type.)

If this helps you please mark it as best answer.